# QListWidgdet resizeEvent QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qlistwidget, qevent

I made class inherit from QListWidget and overrride resizeEvent:

```
void ListaDrzew::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{
    QListWidget::resizeEvent(event);

    int width = event->size().width() / columnNumber - 10;
    setIconSize(QSize(width, width));
    setGridSize(iconSize());
}
```

But sometimes when I resize the the widget by splitter, the application crash with this message:

```
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
```

What is the proper way to change iconSize and gridSize when user resize widget?  I try to use BlockingQueuedConnection and emit signal to yourself, but this make dead lock.

Answer (score 1):

You should not do any actions that can change widget size inside `resizeEvent` because it can lead to infinite recursion. It seems that this is your case. Maybe this quick fix can be used:

```
void ListaDrzew::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{
    QListWidget::resizeEvent(event);
    if (!setting_new_size) {
        setting_new_size = true;
        int width = event->size().width() / columnNumber - 10;
        setIconSize(QSize(width, width));
        setGridSize(iconSize());
        setting_new_size = false;
     }

}
```

(`bool setting_new_size` is a private class member variable).

However this is a logic error. You just can't change icon size based on widget size because they depend on each other. You should use some other parameter for calculating (e.g. top level window size if it doesn't depend on list's icon size).